# how come i can mount any point with docker

Tags: docker, containers, docker-volume

so check out this command:

```
docker container run -v test_node:/my_app_1 -p 3333:3000 --name test2 node:8.13.0
```

my question is how come the `test_node:/my_app_1` volume mounting is not causing an error, i mean it can't be that it's a volume in `node:8.13.0`, and i'm not using a custom Dockerfile,

also, how come the `/my_app_1` folder is being created automatically. to my knowledge if you want to mount a specific location, you need to use the `RUN mkdir` and `VOLUME` commands in a Dockerfile

PS: the same question goes for bind mounts, doing `$(pwd):/my_app_1` works fine too.

Thank you !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the [docker documentation](https://docs.docker.com/storage/bind-mounts/) on bind-mounts:

> If you use -v or --volume to bind-mount a file or directory that does not yet exist on the Docker host, -v creates the endpoint for you. It is always created as a directory.